# Vue Js : How to load tinymce dynamically base on dropdown select

Tags: vue.js, tinymce

I am trying to load tinymce dynamically base on dropdown select, but I count make this work.

Here is the my [**fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/jpouk4yk/1/)

```
Vue.directive('tinymce', {
bind(el) {
tinymce.init({
  target: el,
  theme: 'modern'
 })
}
})

new Vue({
   el: '#timeline_selections',
   data: {
    timeline_type: ''
  }
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found my own solution

```
Vue.directive('tinymce', {
 inserted: function (el) {
   tinymce.remove();
   tinymce.init({
   target: el,
   theme: 'modern'
  })
 }
})
```